# Removing empty space between divs

Tags: css, html, whitespace, removing-whitespace

This seems to be a common problem and I've tried several solutions, but none seem to work for me. There should be 10px of space between each of these divs, but on the top one there is more like 20px.

I have changed line-height, padding, margins, positioning, and block. There does happen to be an empty

tag (that's another issue!), but even with that tag removed/margins reset the problem does not go away. Any ideas?

In this image, you can see I've selected the div with my CSS editor. There is no visible padding on the top (which would be denoted by a dotted line and no margin. Yet, there is space between the inside grey div and the outside white one.
http://www.ims4u.net/settlements/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWJeC.png

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46wGt/

Answer (score 0):

Your container has a padding top of 10px as does your content. Delete one or the other and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks. I actually do want it to have padding of 10px. What's showing is more like 20px. So while I can remove that and it will visually fix the issue, there is still about 10px of space.

Comment: It is because you have the padding twice that is causing the issue. The `.content` div is almost the same size as the `#container`, aside from the border. If you wanted the padding, make the `.content` margin -10px at the top. But I may not be fully understanding of why you need 20px padding to show as 10px.

Answer (score 0):

........**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/46wGt/2/  ................................

Write this **css**  in your css file

```
#content.hfeed.content{
padding-top:0;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46wGt/2/)***

Comment: Thanks, while that does visually fix the issue I'm not sure it solves the underlying problem. It will do for now, but I'm hoping I can also understand why this is happening because although it's not visible on the page there is still space between the .page div and the .entry-content div. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This question illustrates the reason to do a css reset as part of your styling.  Most browsers have default styling that changes the look and feel of the user experience.

You can include a full blown reset that takes into account numerous features/bugs like http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/2.0.1/normalize.css
or you can include something a little more light-weight like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

This will help you from beating your brains in on questions like "Why does Firefox look like..., but IE look like...?"

If you had used one of these, it would have removed a default 10px margin that many browsers add to the `html` tag (or is it the `body` tag?  can't remember...)